# How to highlight selected item in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have used RecyclerView for showing thumbnails in my Image Editing app.Each item of its comprises of a ImageView(thumbnail) and a textView.In my application I want to **highlight only current selected** thumbnail when clicked.Gone through all the related posts on SO but couldn't find any better solution.

**My Adapter Class**

```
    public class FiltersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FiltersAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Type> mDataSet;
    private Uri selectedPhoto;

    public enum Type {
        Original,
        Grayscale,
        Sepia,
        Contrast,
        Invert,
        Pixel,
        Sketch,
        Swirl,
        Brightness,
        Vignette
    }

    public FiltersAdapter(Context context, List<Type> dataSet, Uri selectedPhoto) {
        mContext = context;
        mDataSet = dataSet;
        this.selectedPhoto = selectedPhoto;
    }

    @Override
    public FiltersAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_item_layout, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FiltersAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        switch (mDataSet.get(position)) {
            case Original:
                holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_filter);
                break;
            case Grayscale:
                Picasso.with(mContext)
                        .load(R.drawable.no_filter)
                        .transform(new GrayscaleTransformation())
                        .into(holder.image);
                break;
            case Sepia:
                Picasso.with(mContext)
                        .load(R.drawable.no_filter)
                        .transform(new SepiaFilterTransformation(mContext))
                        .into(holder.image);
                break;
            case Contrast:
                Picasso.with(mContext)
                        .load(R.drawable.no_filter)
                        .transform(new ContrastFilterTransformation(mContext, 2.0f))
                        .into(holder.image);
                break;
            case Invert:
                Picasso.with(mContext)
                        .load(R.drawable.no_filter)
                        .transform(new InvertFilterTransformation(mContext))
                        .into(holder.image);
                break;
            case Pixel:
                Picasso.with(mContext)
                        .load(R.drawable.no_filter)
                        .transform(new PixelationFilterTransformation(mContext, 20))
                        .into(holder.image);
                break;
            case Sketch:
                Picasso.with(mContext)
                        .load(R.drawable.no_filter)
                        .transform(new SketchFilterTransformation(mContext))
                        .into(holder.image);
                break;
            case Swirl:
                Picasso.with(mContext)
                        .load(R.drawable.no_filter)
                        .transform(new SwirlFilterTransformation(mContext, 0.5f, 1.0f, new PointF(0.5f, 0.5f)))
                        .into(holder.image);
                break;
            case Brightness:
                Picasso.with(mContext)
                        .load(R.drawable.no_filter)
                        .transform(new BrightnessFilterTransformation(mContext, 0.5f))
                        .into(holder.image);
                break;
            case Vignette:
                Picasso.with(mContext)
                        .load(R.drawable.no_filter)
                        .transform(new VignetteFilterTransformation(mContext, new PointF(0.5f, 0.5f),
                                new float[]{0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f}, 0f, 0.75f))
                        .into(holder.image);
                break;
            default:
                holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_filter);
                break;

        }
        holder.title.setText(mDataSet.get(position).name());
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewAttachedToWindow(ViewHolder holder) {
        super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataSet.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ImageView image;
        public TextView title;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnailImage);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        }


    }
}
```

**Fragment Code**

```
horizontalFilters = (RecyclerView) mView.findViewById(R.id.rvHorizontal);
    LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManagaer
            = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    horizontalFilters.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManagaer);

    List<Type> dataSet = new ArrayList<>();
    dataSet.add(Type.Original);
    dataSet.add(Type.Grayscale);
    dataSet.add(Type.Sepia);
    dataSet.add(Type.Contrast);
    dataSet.add(Type.Invert);
    dataSet.add(Type.Pixel);
    dataSet.add(Type.Sketch);
    dataSet.add(Type.Swirl);
    dataSet.add(Type.Brightness);
    dataSet.add(Type.Vignette);

    horizontalFilters.setAdapter(new FiltersAdapter(act, dataSet, selectedPhotoUri));

    horizontalFilters.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerClick(act, horizontalFilters, new RecyclerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    photo.setImageDrawable(drawable);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Picasso.with(act)
                            .load(selectedPhotoUri)
                            .transform(new GrayscaleTransformation())
                            .into(photo);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Picasso.with(act)
                            .load(selectedPhotoUri)
                            .transform(new SepiaFilterTransformation(act))
                            .into(photo);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Picasso.with(act)
                            .load(selectedPhotoUri)
                            .transform(new ContrastFilterTransformation(act, 2.0f))
                            .into(photo);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Picasso.with(act)
                            .load(selectedPhotoUri)
                            .transform(new InvertFilterTransformation(act))
                            .into(photo);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    Picasso.with(act)
                            .load(selectedPhotoUri)
                            .transform(new PixelationFilterTransformation(act, 20))
                            .into(photo);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    Picasso.with(act)
                            .load(selectedPhotoUri)
                            .transform(new SketchFilterTransformation(act))
                            .into(photo);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    Picasso.with(act)
                            .load(selectedPhotoUri)
                            .transform(new SwirlFilterTransformation(act, 0.5f, 1.0f, new PointF(0.5f, 0.5f)))
                            .into(photo);
                    break;
                case 8:
                    Picasso.with(act)
                            .load(selectedPhotoUri)
                            .transform(new BrightnessFilterTransformation(act, 0.5f))
                            .into(photo);
                    break;
                case 9:
                    Picasso.with(act)
                            .load(selectedPhotoUri)
                            .transform(new VignetteFilterTransformation(act, new PointF(0.5f, 0.5f),
                                    new float[]{0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f}, 0f, 0.75f))
                            .into(photo);
                    break;
                default:
                    photo.setImageDrawable(drawable);
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

        }
    }));
}
```

Comment: do you have any clickListener or something so that you knows that you select/click on something ?

Comment: Yes, I have used a customized Listener...do you want me to add that code?

Comment: is it possible for you to change form 'public enum Type' to 'public class Type' as a model ??

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Just add this below line in bindView

```
holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
```

will work for you.

if you want to highlight a selected item just do like below

set it global

```
int selectedPosition=-1;
```

inside onBindViewHolder-

```
public void onBindViewHolder(FiltersAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
if(selectedPosition==position)
  holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
else
  holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectedPosition=position;
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
}
```

===========================================================

Above code works fine as per old school methodology but here is the updated version which might help you:

**Kotlin-**

If you want to highlight a selected item just follow:

```
var selectedPosition = -1; //make it global
```

inside onBindViewHolder-

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: FiltersAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
            if (selectedPosition == position)
                holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"))
            else
                holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"))
        }
```

And create inner class ViewHolder which implements `View.OnClickListener` and override the `onClick` function.

```
override fun onClick(v: View) {
      when (v.id) {
           R.id.parent-> {
               selectedPosition = adapterPosition;
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
               }
           }
       }
```

Cheers.

Comment: dint work...it added background to entire recyclerview

Comment: it will add background just to you recycleView's item not recycleView. And your item doesn't contain margin so it fill in your entire recycle view, add margin to your item layout.

Comment: but I also want to deselect previous selected item and highlight only concurrent item...your answer doesn't do that...it only set background to items

Comment: also - position can't be used inside callback since it is not declared with final

Comment: @Amit Bhati  notifyDataSetChanged(); not work well for me its set colour on click, when I click on another it doesn't change

Comment: use notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition) instead of notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: This thing worked only when there are less items once the items list goes bigger it does't work and behaves differently

Comment: @PraveenPanishetti it will work absolutely fine even with large number of data.

Comment: It worked fine for me ...but What happens when you click on same item twice ?  For me it behaved totally different

Comment: @PraveenPanishetti it will work same as you can read code it will store the click position and work accordingly, so there will be no issue.

Comment: Many likes for this answer, Thumbs'p dude.

Comment: This is wrong and behaves unexpectedly also you should not implement your click listener inside onBindViewHolder and using notifyDataSetChanged is should be your last resort.

Comment: @YaMiN then do you have other way?

Comment: @AhChing11 Click listener should be implemented in `ViewHolder` constructor or `onCreateView`, background color could be changed using a `selector` XML and in `onBindViewHolder` only view could be checked or unchecked.

Comment: @YaMiN your answer seems to be what Monu Surana posted. But he didn't post the logic for unselected previously selected item, can you post a new answer? Because I've tried it on my `FlexboxLayout`, and it doesn't work. Only this answer works. But ya i moved my `onClick` to `ViewHolder` class, checking of position in `onBindViewHolder`. Then it works fine. But when i try using `selector`, it shows error

Answer (score 13):

Use background selector and set that in **android:background** property in the layout xml for the recyclerview item

**background_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/lightPrimaryColor" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_selected="false">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

**recyclerview_item.xml** (background_selector is set in android:background property)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp">
```

And then the place where you get the click event you can set it as selected with the View function

**view.setSelected(true)**

You would have to implement the logic for when you want to unselect/select the item by storing the position of selected items

Comment: Need take the previously selected view in global variable and need to make selected false

Answer (score 6):

May be just use:

`android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"`

for root element at item xml?

Comment: should be `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`

Answer (score 4):

Create a Model CalenderModel name

```
class CalenderModel {
var date: String
var isselected: Boolean
constructor(date: String, isselected: Boolean) {
    this.date = date
    this.isselected = isselected
}
 }
```

Create a Adapter CalenderAdapter name

```
class CalenderAdapter(
internal var activity: Activity,
internal var calenderModelList: ArrayList<CalenderModel>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CalenderAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {
var selected_defoult = 0
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
    val itemView: View
    itemView =
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_calenderdate, 
parent, false)
    return MyViewHolder(itemView)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val list = calenderModelList.get(position)
    holder.date_tv.text = Common.formateDate_calender_date(list.date)
    holder.day_tv.text = Common.formateDate_calender_day(list.date)
    if (position <= 3) {
        if (list.isselected) {
            holder.mLinearLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(
                ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                    activity,
                    R.drawable.selected_calender_background_green
                )
            )
        } else {
            holder.mLinearLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(
                ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                    activity,
                    R.drawable.selected_calender_background_gray
                )
            )
        }
    } else {
        holder.mLinearLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(
            ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                activity,
                R.drawable.selected_calender_background_gray_light
            )
        )
    }

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        if (position <= 3) {
            calenderModelList.get(selected_defoult).isselected = false
            calenderModelList.get(position).isselected = true
            selected_defoult = position
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }

   }

 override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return calenderModelList.size
 }

override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
    return position.toLong()
}

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return position
}


inner class MyViewHolder
internal constructor(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    val day_tv: TextView
    val date_tv: TextView
    val mLinearLayout: LinearLayout

    init {
        mLinearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mLinearLayout)
        day_tv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.day_tv)
        date_tv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_tv)

    }
 }


 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So we have a class ViewHolder and a method OnBindViewHolder() in recycler view ok?
now when you click an item in recycler view then the OnClickMethod is called for that view from the view holder class. Now create an integer variable `int previousClickedItemPosition = -1 ;`

Now in the onClickListener method in viewHolderClass put this line,
`previousClickedItemPosition = getAdapterPosition();`
From here we have the position of the item we clicked recently.

Now in OnBindViewHolder() set the colour of the item Background like blue,

`holder.fileNameTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE)`

now In OnclickListener put these line

```
holder.fileNameTextView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);

if(previousClickedItemPosition != getAdapterPosition()) {
notifyDataSetchanged(previousClickedItemPosition );
}
```

The tip is that when we call notifyDataSetchanged then onBindViewHolder is called.

SO when you start recycler view all colour will be blue.
When you click an item colour will be yellow.
When you click next item then the previous item colour will be blue and for current item, the colour will be yellow.

Answer (score 0):

update your enum to class first for flag

```
public class Type {
    public int type; // 0-Original,1-Grayscale,2-Sepia.... same as enum
    public int selected;
}
```

now in adapter

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(FiltersAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    int typeOfItem = mDataSet.get(position).type
    switch (mDataSet.get(position)) {
        case 0:
            holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_filter);
            break;
        case 1:
            Picasso.with(mContext)
                    .load(R.drawable.no_filter)
                    .transform(new GrayscaleTransformation())
                    .into(holder.image);
            break;
        case 2:
            Picasso.with(mContext)
                    .load(R.drawable.no_filter)
                    .transform(new SepiaFilterTransformation(mContext))
                    .into(holder.image);
            break;
        case 3:
            Picasso.with(mContext)
                    .load(R.drawable.no_filter)
                    .transform(new ContrastFilterTransformation(mContext, 2.0f))
                    .into(holder.image);
            break;
        case 4:
            Picasso.with(mContext)
                    .load(R.drawable.no_filter)
                    .transform(new InvertFilterTransformation(mContext))
                    .into(holder.image);
            break;
        case 5:
            Picasso.with(mContext)
                    .load(R.drawable.no_filter)
                    .transform(new PixelationFilterTransformation(mContext, 20))
                    .into(holder.image);
            break;
        case 6:
            Picasso.with(mContext)
                    .load(R.drawable.no_filter)
                    .transform(new SketchFilterTransformation(mContext))
                    .into(holder.image);
            break;
        case 7:
            Picasso.with(mContext)
                    .load(R.drawable.no_filter)
                    .transform(new SwirlFilterTransformation(mContext, 0.5f, 1.0f, new PointF(0.5f, 0.5f)))
                    .into(holder.image);
            break;
        case 8:
            Picasso.with(mContext)
                    .load(R.drawable.no_filter)
                    .transform(new BrightnessFilterTransformation(mContext, 0.5f))
                    .into(holder.image);
            break;
        case 9:
            Picasso.with(mContext)
                    .load(R.drawable.no_filter)
                    .transform(new VignetteFilterTransformation(mContext, new PointF(0.5f, 0.5f),
                            new float[]{0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f}, 0f, 0.75f))
                    .into(holder.image);
            break;
        default:
            holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_filter);
            break;
    }
    holder.title.setText(mDataSet.get(position).name());
    if(mDataSet.get(position).selected == 0){
        holder.title.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    } else {
        holder.title.setTypeface(null,Typeface.NORMAL);
    }
}
```

not on every click or select update your list then call notifydatasetChanged() of adapter

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin you can simply do what some folks have already mentioned for Java. You put this code in your adapter class.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    if (position < numItems) {
        // Bind your view here
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            it.setBackgroundResource(R.color.lightBlue)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you **don't** want to use notifyDataSetChanged
Implemented by kotlin

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    adapterOrders = OrdersSendAdapter(this, listOrders)
    recyclerOrders = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_orders)
    recyclerOrders.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    recyclerOrders.setHasFixedSize(true)
    recyclerOrders.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(activity, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL))
    recyclerOrders.adapter = adapterOrders
  }

/* This method will be call when item of adapter has an event */
fun getListDetail(position: Int, idOrders: String) {
    for (index in 0 until recyclerOrders.childCount) {
         recyclerOrders[index].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"))
    }
    recyclerOrders[position].setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.color_select))
}
```