# Can't select single item and track position of the item on RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to select and highlight the the row of the `recyclerview` with current time on clicking the days. I can show the rows on clicking the week days. But can't highlight or `setBackground` to the rows with current time. 
Once I compare the `position` with the position from the `onBindHolder()` method the numbers of rows are `highlighted`.

Please help me with it. Thank You

[image: The week days are clickable and set rows to other <code>recyclerView</code> and should highlight or set custom drawable background with current time.]

This line of code `setAdapter()` and smooth scrolling to the current time position:

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date date = calendar.getTime();

    int onEpgDaysPosition = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    int onAirEpgPosition = getpositionofOnAir(epgHash.get(new SimpleDateFormat("EE", Locale.ENGLISH).format(date.getTime())));

    daysRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(PlayerNewActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

    EpgDaysRecyclerViewAdapter epgDaysListAdapter = new EpgDaysRecyclerViewAdapter(PlayerNewActivity.this, epgHash, epgKey, epgRecyclerView);
    daysRecyclerView.setAdapter(epgDaysListAdapter);


    epgRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(PlayerNewActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    EpgDvrRecyclerViewAdapter epgListAdapter = new EpgDvrRecyclerViewAdapter(PlayerNewActivity.this, epgHash, epgKey, new SimpleDateFormat("EE", Locale.ENGLISH).format(date.getTime()));
    epgRecyclerView.setAdapter(epgListAdapter);

    daysRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManagerWithSmoothScroller(PlayerNewActivity.this));
    daysRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(onEpgDaysPosition);

    epgRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManagerWithSmoothScroller(PlayerNewActivity.this));
    epgRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(onAirEpgPosition);
```

This is the `RecyclerViewAdapter`:

```
public class EpgDvrRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EpgDvrRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private HashMap<String, ArrayList<Epg>> epgHash;
private ArrayList<String> epgKey;
private ArrayList<Epg> individualDayEpg;
private String key;


public EpgDvrRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context,
                                 HashMap<String, ArrayList<Epg>> epgHash, ArrayList<String> epgKey, String key) {

    this.context = context;
    this.epgHash = epgHash;
    this.epgKey = epgKey;
    this.key = key;
    individualDayEpg = epgHash.get(key);

}


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.epg_individual_dvr, null);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Epg epg = individualDayEpg.get(position);

    holder.programName.setText(epg.getProgramName());
    holder.programTime.setText(epg.getProgramStartTime() + " - " + epg.getProgramEndTime());

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm");
    int s = Integer.parseInt(sdf.format(new Date()));
    if (Integer.parseInt(epg.getProgramStartTime().replace(":", "")) <= s && s <= Integer.parseInt(epg.getProgramEndTime().replace(":", ""))) {
        holder.epgRow.setSelected(true);
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return individualDayEpg.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View v;
    private TextView programName, programTime;
    private LinearLayout epgRow;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        v = itemView;

        epgRow = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.epgRow);
        programName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.epgProgramName);
        programTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.epgProgramTime);

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: have you created selector xml for defining colors/drawables for different select states ?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39138315/how-to-highlight-selected-item-in-recyclerview/39138565#39138565) out.

Comment: yes i have also created the selector xml. It also select the rows but it doesn't select the specific row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**SparseBooleanArray**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseBooleanArray.html) to save the current selected item.

Do the following in your RecyclerView Adapter class:

```
// Initialize variable to hold the selected item.
SparseBooleanArray mSelectedItems = new SparseBooleanArray();

// When selecting an item, save it
mSelectedItems.put(your_item_position, true); // Set true when selected

// Then in your view binding, set based on the selection saved before
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
  ...
  if(mSelectedItem.get(position)) {
    // set as selected here
  } else {
    // set as not selected here.
    // SparseBoolean always return false if we haven't add the value yet.
  }
  ...
}
```

---

#### UPDATE

If you want to select only one week days, you can do it by resetting to false all the data in **SparseBooleanArray** except the current selected item position. Then you need to call `notifyItemChanged(int position)`.

Something like this:

```
// Do this when you selecting an item:
// save it
mSelectedItems.put(your_item_position, true); // Set true when selected

// Then you reset the items check of the other items
final int checkedItemCount = mSelectedItems.size();
for (int i = 0; i < checkedItemCount; i++) {
  int position = checkedItemPositions.keyAt(i); // item position in the list.
  // reset position except the current selected item.
  if (position != your_item_position) { 
    if (checkedItemPositions.get(position)) { 
       // Item is checked. Need to uncheck it.
       mSelectedItems.put(position, false);
       // notify the change to Adapter
       notifyItemChanged(position);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually i also want help with the week days recyclerview. I want to highlight only one day. For example, when i click "SUN", the background of "WED" must be gone. How can i do that?

Comment: I guess you want to select only one week days, right? You can do it by resetting to false all the data in SparseBooleanArray except the current selected item position. Then you need to call [notifyItemChanged(int position)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int,%20java.lang.Object))

Comment: How can i do it could you give an example?

Comment: @KabindraShrestha: I've included the example. Please be note that I haven't try the code.

Comment: glad it help you ;)

Answer (score 2):

Create a selector in your drawable folder like below and set it as background to the LinearLayout of the row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="false" 
          android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:state_selected="true"  
          android:drawable="@android:color/background_dark" />
</selector>
```

Comment: I have already used the custom selector. But it doesn't work. When i setSelected(true), the item i want to select does select but other items also get selected when i scroll up and down in the recycler view.