# How can I highlight row of a recyclerview while scrolling?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, highlight

Currently, I have implemented a recyclerview with different view types. Now my question is that how can I highlight a particular while scrolling through recyclerview. (Recyclerview has rows with dynamic hight, Highlight means making other rows greyed and current row's views to some theme).

Can anyone help me out?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39138315/how-to-highlight-selected-item-in-recyclerview)

Comment: I want to highlight while scrolling not by clicking the row, anyways thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution see below code

```
Integer firstVisibleItem = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
Integer lastVisibleItem = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastVisibleItemPosition();
```

So now

```
position_to_highlighten = (lastVisibleItem + firstVisibleItem)/2
```

Comment: But how can I get the positions of the items while scrolling? Highlighting is not a major issue for me for but fetching the current location is bit tricky for me.

Comment: How are you describing which row to highlight(Which row you want to highlight) ??

Comment: do you want to highlight all new rows user scroling or not ??

Comment: the item which is center of the screen is to be highlighted and others will be greyed.

Comment: and the hight of the rows are dynamic so there will be two or three or even four visible rows, so when users scrolls, the center one will be highlighted.

Comment: but i guess your code will not work for last position and first position.

Comment: why what is happening with you ??

Comment: I said you view height is dynamic, so there can be three views at a time. so it will difficult to handle such situation when recyclerview is at the bottom position.

Comment: why it will be difficult i am not getting, you want center item position which you are clearly getting through my code ?? Is my code not giving you center item position ??

Comment: nop, its not working for last position because in my case, there are three items on the screen and no scroll is there and your logic will give last to second element , so last element will never be highlighted.

Comment: You have three items and no scroll so (first + last)/2 will be (0 + 2)/2 which is 1 so isn't it right because now 1 will get highlighted which is the centre item ?? If it is wrong then what functionality you want can you please explain in detail in your question it is very confusing ??

Comment: but what if i want to highlight the last item, then this login will not work, and  i don't want to apply hard-coded logic for the last item.

Comment: do you want to highlist last item because it is at the center of the screen ?? i thought you want to highlight center position item(irrespective of the screen). ??