# Change background color of selected item in recyclerview

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view with linearlayout and textviews inside cardview. I would like to implement onclick method for my item where in I would like to change the background color of the linear layout and invert the textcolor of the textviews. I have got it working but the main issue I am facing is that if I select 1st item then 1st as well as 7th items color is changed.

Trying to get this to work since two days. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Models.ViewModels;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Support.V7.Widget;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace A.Droid.Adapters
{
    public class DeliveryAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter//, View.IOnClickListener
    {
        List<RequestViewModel> list;
        public Context v;
        public event EventHandler<int> phoneClick;

        List<RequestViewModel> selectedList = new List<RequestViewModel>();

        public DeliveryAdapter(List<RequestViewModel> records, Context v1)
        {
            list = records;
            v = v1;
        }
        public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            // Inflate the CardView for the photo:
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.activity_cardview_slinkyRecordList, parent, false);

            DeliveryListViewHolder vh = new DeliveryListViewHolder(itemView, OnPhoneClick);
            return vh;
        }

        // Fill in the contents of the photo card (invoked by the layout manager):
        public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {
            DeliveryListViewHolder viewHolder = holder as DeliveryListViewHolder;
            viewHolder.PICNumber.Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(list[position].PICNumber) ? "-" : list[position].PICNumber;
            viewHolder.PropertyName.Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(list[position].PropertyName) ? "-" : list[position].PropertyName;
            viewHolder.ContactAddress.Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(list[position].ContactAddress) ? "-" : list[position].ContactAddress;
            viewHolder.ContactPerson.Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(list[position].ContactPerson) ? "-" : list[position].ContactPerson;
            viewHolder.ContactNumber.Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(list[position].ContactNumber) ? "-" : list[position].ContactNumber;

            viewHolder.NumberOfAliveSpecies.Text = list[position].NumberOfAliveStock + " Alive " + list[position].NameOfSpecies;
            viewHolder.NumberOfDeadSpecies.Text = list[position].NumberOfDeadStock + " Dead " + list[position].NameOfSpecies;

            viewHolder.DistanceOfTransporterToPIC.Text = list[position].DistanceOfTransporterFromPIC.ToString() + " KM"; //DeliveryList[position].DistanceOfTransporterFromPIC.ToString();
                                                                                                                         //viewHolder.MainLinearLayout.SetOnClickListener((new OnClickListener(viewHolder.MainLinearLayout,position));                                                                         // cardViewList.Add(viewHolder.cardView); //add all the cards to this list
                                                                                                                         //viewHolder.MainLinearLayout.SetOnClickListener(this);                                                                        // cardViewList.Add(viewHolder.cardView); //add all the cards to this list

            viewHolder.cardView.Click += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (selectedList.All(i => i.slinkyStockRequestId != list[position].slinkyStockRequestId))
                {
                    selectedList.Add(list[position]);

                    viewHolder.MainLinearLayout.SetBackgroundColor(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.white));

                    viewHolder.PICNumber.SetTextColor(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.dark_blue));
                    viewHolder.PropertyName.SetTextColor(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.dark_blue));
                    viewHolder.ContactAddress.SetTextColor(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.dark_blue));
                    viewHolder.ContactPerson.SetTextColor(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.dark_blue));
                    viewHolder.ContactNumber.SetTextColor(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.dark_blue));

                    viewHolder.NumberOfAliveSpecies.SetTextColor(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.dark_blue));
                    viewHolder.NumberOfDeadSpecies.SetTextColor(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.dark_blue));

                    viewHolder.DistanceOfTransporterToPIC.SetTextColor(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.dark_blue));
                    viewHolder.mapIcon.SetColorFilter(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.dark_blue), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);
                    viewHolder.contactIcon.SetColorFilter(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.dark_blue), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);
                    viewHolder.phoneIcon.SetColorFilter(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.dark_blue), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);

                }
                else
                {
                    selectedList.Remove(list[position]);

                    viewHolder.MainLinearLayout.SetBackgroundColor(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.dark_blue));

                    viewHolder.PICNumber.SetTextColor(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.white));
                    viewHolder.PropertyName.SetTextColor(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.white));
                    viewHolder.ContactAddress.SetTextColor(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.white));
                    viewHolder.ContactPerson.SetTextColor(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.white));
                    viewHolder.ContactNumber.SetTextColor(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.white));

                    viewHolder.NumberOfAliveSpecies.SetTextColor(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.white));
                    viewHolder.NumberOfDeadSpecies.SetTextColor(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.white));

                    viewHolder.DistanceOfTransporterToPIC.SetTextColor(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.white));
                    viewHolder.mapIcon.SetColorFilter(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);
                    viewHolder.contactIcon.SetColorFilter(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);
                    viewHolder.phoneIcon.SetColorFilter(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);

                }
            };



            animate(holder);
        }


        public List<RequestViewModel> GetSelectedItems()
        {
            return selectedList;
        }


        // Return the number of photos available in the photo album:
        public override int ItemCount
        {
            get { return list.Count; }
        }


        // Raise an event when the phone-click takes place:
        void OnPhoneClick(int position)
        {
            if (phoneClick != null)
            {
                phoneClick(this, position);
            }
        }


        public class DeliveryListViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        {
            public ImageView MapTag { get; private set; }
            public TextView PICNumber { get; private set; }
            public TextView PropertyName { get; private set; }
            public TextView ContactAddress { get; private set; }
            public TextView ContactPerson { get; private set; }
            public TextView ContactNumber { get; private set; }
            public TextView NameOfSpecies { get; private set; }
            public TextView NumberOfAliveSpecies { get; private set; }
            public TextView NumberOfDeadSpecies { get; private set; }
            public TextView DistanceOfTransporterToPIC { get; private set; }
            public CardView cardView { get; private set; }
            public LinearLayout MainLinearLayout { get; private set; }
            public ImageView mapIcon { get; private set; }
            public ImageView contactIcon { get; private set; }
            public ImageView phoneIcon { get; private set; }
            // Get references to the views defined in the CardView layout.
            public DeliveryListViewHolder(View itemView, Action<int> phoneClickListener) : base(itemView)
            {
                MapTag = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.mapIcon);
                PICNumber = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.PICNumber);
                PropertyName = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.nameOfProperty);
                ContactPerson = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.contactPerson);
                NumberOfAliveSpecies = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.noOfAliveSpecies);
                NumberOfDeadSpecies = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.noOfDeadSpecies);
                DistanceOfTransporterToPIC = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.areaInKM);
                ContactAddress = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.address);
                ContactNumber = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.mobileNo);
                mapIcon = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.mapIcon);
                contactIcon = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.contactIcon);
                phoneIcon = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.phoneIcon);

                cardView = itemView.FindViewById<CardView>(Resource.Id.mainCardviewLayout);
                MainLinearLayout = itemView.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.MainLinearLayout);
                ContactNumber.Click += (sender, e) => phoneClickListener(base.Position);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

**Edit**
From `Deep Patel` input, here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Models.ViewModels;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Support.V7.Widget;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace A.Droid.Adapters
{
    public class DeliveryAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter//, View.IOnClickListener
    {
        List<RequestViewModel> list;
        public Context v;
        public event EventHandler<int> phoneClick;

        List<RequestViewModel> selectedList = new List<RequestViewModel>();

        public DeliveryAdapter(List<RequestViewModel> records, Context v1)
        {
            list = records;
            v = v1;
        }
        public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            // Inflate the CardView for the photo:
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.activity_cardview_slinkyRecordList, parent, false);

            DeliveryListViewHolder vh = new DeliveryListViewHolder(itemView, OnPhoneClick);
            return vh;
        }

        public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        DeliveryListViewHolder viewHolder = holder as DeliveryListViewHolder;
        viewHolder.PICNumber.Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(list[position].PICNumber) ? "-" : list[position].PICNumber;
        viewHolder.PropertyName.Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(list[position].PropertyName) ? "-" : list[position].PropertyName;
        viewHolder.ContactAddress.Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(list[position].ContactAddress) ? "-" : list[position].ContactAddress;
        viewHolder.ContactPerson.Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(list[position].ContactPerson) ? "-" : list[position].ContactPerson;
        viewHolder.ContactNumber.Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(list[position].ContactNumber) ? "-" : list[position].ContactNumber;

        viewHolder.NumberOfAliveSpecies.Text = list[position].NumberOfAliveStock + " Alive " + list[position].NameOfSpecies;
        viewHolder.NumberOfDeadSpecies.Text = list[position].NumberOfDeadStock + " Dead " + list[position].NameOfSpecies;

        viewHolder.DistanceOfTransporterToPIC.Text = list[position].DistanceOfTransporterFromPIC.ToString() + " KM"; //DeliveryList[position].DistanceOfTransporterFromPIC.ToString();
                                                                                                                     //viewHolder.MainLinearLayout.SetOnClickListener((new OnClickListener(viewHolder.MainLinearLayout,position));                                                                         // cardViewList.Add(viewHolder.cardView); //add all the cards to this list
                                                                                                                     //viewHolder.MainLinearLayout.SetOnClickListener(this);                                                                        // cardViewList.Add(viewHolder.cardView); //add all the cards to this list

        viewHolder.cardView.Click += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            setSelectedPosition(position);
        };

        viewHolder.MainLinearLayout.SetBackgroundColor(list[position].isSelected() ? v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.white) : v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.dark_blue));


        animate(holder);
    }

    private void setSelectedPosition(int position)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count(); i++)
        {
            list[position].setSelected(i == position);
        }
        NotifyDataSetChanged();
    }

        public List<RequestViewModel> GetSelectedItems()
        {
            return selectedList;
        }


        // Return the number of photos available in the photo album:
        public override int ItemCount
        {
            get { return list.Count; }
        }


        // Raise an event when the phone-click takes place:
        void OnPhoneClick(int position)
        {
            if (phoneClick != null)
            {
                phoneClick(this, position);
            }
        }


        public class DeliveryListViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        {
            public ImageView MapTag { get; private set; }
            public TextView PICNumber { get; private set; }
            public TextView PropertyName { get; private set; }
            public TextView ContactAddress { get; private set; }
            public TextView ContactPerson { get; private set; }
            public TextView ContactNumber { get; private set; }
            public TextView NameOfSpecies { get; private set; }
            public TextView NumberOfAliveSpecies { get; private set; }
            public TextView NumberOfDeadSpecies { get; private set; }
            public TextView DistanceOfTransporterToPIC { get; private set; }
            public CardView cardView { get; private set; }
            public LinearLayout MainLinearLayout { get; private set; }
            public ImageView mapIcon { get; private set; }
            public ImageView contactIcon { get; private set; }
            public ImageView phoneIcon { get; private set; }
            // Get references to the views defined in the CardView layout.
            public DeliveryListViewHolder(View itemView, Action<int> phoneClickListener) : base(itemView)
            {
                MapTag = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.mapIcon);
                PICNumber = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.PICNumber);
                PropertyName = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.nameOfProperty);
                ContactPerson = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.contactPerson);
                NumberOfAliveSpecies = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.noOfAliveSpecies);
                NumberOfDeadSpecies = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.noOfDeadSpecies);
                DistanceOfTransporterToPIC = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.areaInKM);
                ContactAddress = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.address);
                ContactNumber = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.mobileNo);
                mapIcon = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.mapIcon);
                contactIcon = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.contactIcon);
                phoneIcon = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.phoneIcon);

                cardView = itemView.FindViewById<CardView>(Resource.Id.mainCardviewLayout);
                MainLinearLayout = itemView.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.MainLinearLayout);
                ContactNumber.Click += (sender, e) => phoneClickListener(base.Position);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39138315/how-to-highlight-selected-item-in-recyclerview please check it I hope to help it.

Comment: Please add xamarin tag to question .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **in your model,
>   take a boolean variable, and create getter setter methods**

```
private boolean isSelected = false

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        isSelected = selected;
    }
```

> **in your  `OnBindViewHolder`**

```
viewHolder.MainLinearLayout.SetBackgroundColor(list[position].isSelected()?v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.white):v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.black));
```

> **in your onClick event,**  // Code below is edited

**Note:** For Best practice `setTag(position)` with your position to your view that is getting clicked and use that tag value as a position.

```
int pos = (int) view.getTag(); 
list[pos].setSelected(!list[pos].isSelected());
                        notifyItemChanged(position);
```

Comment: I am using Xamarin. Does Xamarin has setSelected?

Comment: @Arti : when you will have that boolean variable in your model, and create a getter setter, it will be created in your model. 
Please check updated answer

Comment: You code works fine but I also need to deselect items. How can keep track of that as well?

Comment: or please mention what issue you are facing

Comment: Please check last updated ans. and there you go. Happy Coding, and dont forget to do the necessary ;)

Comment: Deep, the selection and deselection does not work now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168102/discussion-between-arti-and-deep-patel).

Comment: It does not work as expected, it does not select multiple but instead selects one at a time

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the background color of your view at `OnBindViewHolder()` because views are reused here

Add these lines on your `OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)`

```
if (selectedList.All(i => i.slinkyStockRequestId != list[position].slinkyStockRequestId)) 
viewHolder.MainLinearLayout.SetBackgroundColor(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.C olor.white));
else 
viewHolder.MainLinearLayout.SetBackgroundColor(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.dark_blue));
```

Comment: I have done a check  **if (selectedList.All(i => i.slinkyStockRequestId != list[position].slinkyStockRequestId))** But does not help

Comment: can you update your `OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)` with your recent changes ? So I can check

Comment: Add my lines after `DeliveryListViewHolder viewHolder = holder as DeliveryListViewHolder;`

Comment: when you scroll on bindviewHolder will call

Comment: As you can see in my code above, I have added that code after DeliveryListViewHolder viewHolder = holder as DeliveryListViewHolder; already

Comment: yes but you put it on onclick,so it's will work when you click again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168090/discussion-between-arti-and-rajasekaran-m).