# Visually highlight clicked item in RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

How can I visually highlight the clicked element within a RecyclerView? I currently have the following approach. If I click on a certain element, its text becomes bold. Problem: If I click on several elements in a row, they all get the bold style. However, only the current one should be marked in bold.

CategoryAdapter.kt:

```
class CategoryAdapter(val list:ArrayList<Categorys>, mainActivity: MainActivity): RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    private  var listener = mainActivity

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {  
    holder.categoryLayout.setOnClickListener{
           listener.setOnClickListener(list[position],position)
           holder.categoryName!!.typeface = Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD
    }
```

Interface CategoryListener.kt:

```
 interface CategoryListener {
  fun setOnClickListener(category:Categorys,position:Int)
}
```

MainActvity.kt:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CategoryListener {

  override fun setOnClickListener(category: Categorys, position: Int) {
     val category = categoryList[position]
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to highlight selected item in RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39138315/how-to-highlight-selected-item-in-recyclerview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only one single element to be selected you have to store it for row checking on item draw

Here the way to get there

```
private var selectPos = -1

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val cate = list[position]
    val isSelect = this.selectPos == position
    holder.categoryName!!.typeface =
        Typeface.create(
            if (isSelect) Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD else Typeface.DEFAULT,
            if (isSelect) Typeface.BOLD else Typeface.NORMAL
        )
    holder.categoryLayout.setOnClickListener {
        listener.setOnClickListener(cate, position)
        this.selectPos = position
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to add an `else` statement to clear the typeface, or a recycled item will maintain the bold text style after it's clicked.

Comment: yeab , i did forgot .